# MYSQL perform repeated UPDATEs using resulting rows from select statement

Tags: mysql, loops, subquery, repeat

```
UPDATE tb_user SET user_level = user_level - 100 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tb_levels WHERE factor = 10);
```

tb_user:

```
-----------------
 id | user_level
-----------------
  1 | 1000
  2 | 1500
  3 | 3000
  4 | 2500
-----------------
```

tb_levels:

```
-----------------
 id | factor
-----------------
  1 | 10
  1 | 10
  2 | 10
  2 | 10
  3 | 12
  5 | 20
-----------------
```

I thought the result in tb_user should be:

```
-----------------
 id | user_level
-----------------
  1 | 800
  2 | 1300
```

but it is:

```
-----------------
 id | user_level
-----------------
  1 | 900
  2 | 1400
```

How to perform the query for resulting 800 and 1200? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that. Use `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE tb_user u
    JOIN (SELECT id, count(*) AS c FROM tb_levels WHERE factor = 10 GROUP BY id) i ON u.id = i.id
SET user_level = user_level - 100 * i.c
```

Comment: @Georde What about if I need to do it using 3 tables each one having the the same structure, like tb_user1, tb_user2 and tb_user3?

Comment: @RafaelMaia execute this query three times with different table names. It would be to complicated to do it in one query if possible at all. Anyway, one table with extra field (e.g. `type.`) is better than three.

Comment: In fact, I need to do this using 9 distict tables, each one having a different internal structure. But, as you said, it's better call 9 well done queries than one semi-handled query. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count how many occurrences of the id there are in the other table. Try this:

```
UPDATE tb_user SET user_level = user_level - (100 * ct) 
FROM tb_user
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, count(*) ct FROM tb_levels WHERE factor = 10 GROUP BY id
) as idCount ON tb_user.id = idCount.id
```